# Form images not being displayed

Tags: html, css, image

http://croakedslayouts.hol.es/purchase.html
My form images aren't being displayed, but when you click where the div is (underneath the short paragraph) it pops up. Anyone know why? It may be a fault on my end or it might just be my host.

I've added `z-index: 1;` to the CSSbut nothing changed.

Comment: Can you show the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#name {
    background-image: url(images/form/nameunfocus.png);
    ...
}
```

Your image is actually named **NameUnfocus.png** NOT *nameunfocus.png* (see: http://croakedslayouts.hol.es/images/form/). Capital letters matter.

(The reason why it works when you focus on the text box is because the image name provided in the actual form element uses the correct naming convention.)